# Using list get method to get Strings

Tags: java, list

I have an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class Command {
    public abstract void execute(String keyWord[]);
    String keyWord;
    public Command(String keyWord) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
    }
}
```

and a class to manage it like so:

```
public class CommandManager {

    private static List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void append(Command command) {
        commands.add(command);
    }

    static {

    }

    public static void load() {
        append(new Command("lol") {

            @Override
            public void execute(Player player, String[] keyWord) {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean handle() {
        String cmd[] = input.split(" ");
        Command command = commands.get(cmd[0].toLowerCase()); //this
        if (command != null) {
            command.execute(player, cmd);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The error I get is where my comment is. How can I use the the get method to get the String from the Command class?
Thanks

Comment: I take it this is Java? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Give more information about what the error is.

Comment: you need to expose the string from the command class, say by using a getter, a method like String getKeyword() {return keyword;} and then do a command.getKeyword();

Comment: I think the `execute` method inside the `load` method isn't override method. As you see the `execute` just have 1 parameter `String[] keyWord` and when you override you declare 2 parameters `Player player, String[] keyWord`. Please see in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047793/function-override-overload-in-java) for explanation.

Comment: There is some questions I want to ask you regarding the code above:
1. What is the content of `String cmd[]`? As we can see the content based on the `input` that has been split, but I don't know what is the content of the `input`.
2. You using `get(int index)` why your input for the `get` method is String?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the get() method expects an `int` which represents the index of the list.

- [Java SE 6 -- List.get(i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)
- [Java SE 7 -- List.get(i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the the get method to get the String from the Command
>   class?

<del>The simplest</del> *A simple* way is to create getter method of `keyWord` in `Command` class and then

```
commands.get(index).getKeyWord(); //this will return the string
```

Here `index` is an integer variable indicating command class index in list. And don't forget to check for null. Get method would be something like

```
public String getKeyWord() {
    return this.keyWord;
}
```

Comment: Well, the *simplest* method would be to make keyWord public.  Nobody would recommend that - I certainly don't - but it's simpler than a getter.

Comment: @CarlManaster That would be simpler but not a good coding practice, I guess. Generally people avoids that. So we get getter as simpler and better way to do it :p

Answer (score 0):

Commands is an `ArrayList` and the `get()` function takes in a `int` Parameter.

Eithor use numbers or Use a `Map<String,Command>` for your code.

Comment: I used a map previously, just wanted to try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the command that has the matching keyword, so try this:

```
Command command = null;
for (Command c : commands) {
    if (c.keyWord.equalsIgnoreCase(cmd[0])) {
        command = c;
        break;
    }
}

// command will not either be null or be the Command whose keyword matches
```

p.s. I recommend goolging for tutorials on java and OOP.